# MongoDB - how can I query "INTERSECT" of SQL?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I have a question about "INTERSECT" query in the MongoDB query.

I want to query like the following SQL query in MongoDB.

```
(select course_id from section where semester = 'fall' and year = '2009') 
intersect 
(select course_id from section where semester = 'spring' and year = '2010');
```

In my MongoDB, Section collection data structure is as follows.

```
{ 
"_id" : {
    "course_id" : "486", 
    "sec_id" : "1", 
    "semester" : "Fall", 
    "year" : 2009.0
}, 
"course_id" : "486", 
"sec_id" : "1", 
"semester" : "Fall", 
"year" : 2009.0, 
"building" : "Whitman", 
"room_number" : "134", 
"time_slot_id" : "K"
```

}

How to query to get the same result as SQL language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly sexy but you can do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            year: 2009
                        },
                        {
                            semester: "fall"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            year: 2010
                        },
                        {
                            semester: "spring"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$course_id",
            years_x_semester: {$addToSet: {year: "$year", semester: "$semester"}},
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "years_x_semester.1": {$exists: true}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I thought it would work, but after testing it, I couldn't get the results I wanted.:'-(

Comment: What is the result you want?

Comment: It was solved after a little modification! thank you so much!!!